# Text on image in PDF footer using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, footer

I am trying to add an image and page no in my PDF footer. My problem is i'm not able to show the page number on the image. Below is my code.

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    int pageNo=writer.getPageNumber()-this.pageNumber+1;
    Integer dummy=pageNo;
    String pageNoString=dummy.toString();
    PdfContentByte cbb = writer.getDirectContent();

    try {
        ColumnText column = new ColumnText(cbb);
        PdfPTable newtable = new PdfPTable(1);
        newtable.setTotalWidth(530);
        newtable.setLockedWidth(true);
        Image img = Image.getInstance("C:/Users/sathesh/Desktop/Warfiles/PDFFiles/Footer.png");

        PdfPCell imageCell=new PdfPCell();
        PdfPCell textCell=new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Disclaimer text",new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 6, Font.NORMAL)));
        imageCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        textCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            imageCell.setImage(img);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(cbb,
                    Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(pageNoString,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER,12,new BaseColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00))), 50, 95, 0);
            newtable.addCell(imageCell);
        newtable.addCell(textCell);
        column.addElement(newtable);
        column.setSimpleColumn(30, 130, 570, 45,5f, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT | Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM |Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL);
        }
        column.go();
        catch(Exception e)
        {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding the text the hard way? Why don't you use `ColumnText.showAligned()` which makes it much easier to position your text (no need to calculate the sine and cosine). Furthermore, I don't see the point of using `column` without using the `go()` method. You also define an alignment while using `ColumnText` in composite mode (whereas this only works in text mode). Finally: why do you think using `Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM` would work with `setSimpleColumn()`. I'm sorry, but your code is beyond repair. Please start anew from scratch.

Comment: i Forgot to add `column.go();` in this code. I have updated my code. I need help to show the page no just above the image.

Comment: What about all my other comments? Also, think of Sherlock Holmes and Watson: elementary logic can help you. If you add text first and then an image, isn't it normal that the image covers the text? Why don't you switch adding text and image so that the text covers the image. I really hope you consider throwing away your code and starting anew writing decent code. The `setTextMatrix()` method shouldn't be used by people who don't understand what the parameters mean. Use `ColumnText.showAligned()` and the people who have to read your code will thank you!

Comment: I have updated the code using `ColumnText.showTextAligned()` but still the page number is going behind the image. Kindly look into my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(cbb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(pageNoString,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER,12,new BaseColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00))), 50, 95, 0);
newtable.addCell(imageCell);
newtable.addCell(textCell);
column.addElement(newtable);
column.setSimpleColumn(30, 130, 570, 45,5f, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT | Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM |Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL);
column.go();
```

This add the text first, and then covers the text with the table containing the image, hence the image covers the text.

As I said in my comment, you should use elementary logic and try this:

```
newtable.addCell(imageCell);
newtable.addCell(textCell);
column.addElement(newtable);
column.setSimpleColumn(30, 130, 570, 45,5f, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT | Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM |Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL);
column.go();
ColumnText.showTextAligned(cbb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(pageNoString,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER,12,new BaseColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00))), 50, 95, 0);
```

Now the table with the image is added first and the text is written on top of the image.